# Why are some comments deleted immediately upon flagging?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017300/how-to-convert-the-system-date-format-to-dd-mm-yy-in-sql-server-2008-r2), and noticed that the OP had left the same boilerplate comment on two of the answers. Something like:

> Thanks for the answer. I will get back to you.

So I flagged both of those comments as "No longer needed", and they got deleted instantly!

I even checked from incognito window, wondering if they may have been hidden from my view - *for some strange reason* - but they are indeed gone. My flags are also marked "helpful".

So it seems like something has changed about how the "No longer needed" flags on comments are handled. Has it?

Also, to check my theory, I found another ["ok , glad i could help.thanks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017300/how-to-convert-the-system-date-format-to-dd-mm-yy-in-sql-server-2008-r2#comment21100179_15017316) comment on the same question. But when I flagged it, it wasn't auto-deleted. Why?